# Elasticserach 5.X vs Elasticseach 1.7 in respect with memory consumption and index creation, segment merging

Tags: elasticsearch, migration, production-environment

I am migrating my production from ES1.7 to ES5 directly.
But before that, I want to compare memory consumptions of index creation, query etc.

Thanks to all!!

Comment: You should clearly not do that in production first, try to create a staging environment with a subset of your production data. Then you can compare and extrapolate.

Comment: @Val. Thanks for your response. Definitely,  I am not going to do that in production. I am planning for it. First I want to compare between es5 and es 1.7. I am not able to find how indexing is happening inside es5, query working in es5 ..etc etc.

Comment: Understood, then you should prepare another env, feed it with real data and compare both version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many types has been deprecated and created new ones. Your mappings will not work. For instance, a 1.7 not analyzed string becomes in an "keyword" and so on. Some other filters has been deprecated and now you have to call them as queries and vice versa.

To do such migration you will have to set up a dev environment and refactor many of your queries.